# Argument of type (key: string, id: string, pagination: number) => Promise<void> is not assignable to parameter of type Boolean

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Not sure what is the matter here, but I am trying to follow this documentation:

https://swr.vercel.app/

with this setup of my own:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import PatientsTable from 'components/patients/PatientsTable'
import useSWR from 'hooks/useSWRWithToken'
import Feedback from 'components/feedback'
import fetchWithToken from 'libs/fetchWithToken'

function Patients(props) {
  const {page, rowsPerPage, onPageChange, query, accessToken } = props

  const fetcher = async (key: string, id: string, pagination: number)=> {
    fetchWithToken(key, accessToken, [id, page: pagination])
  }
  
    const { data: patientsList, error: patientsListError, isLoading } = useSWR(
      [`patients/${id}`, id, pagination], fetcher)
  

  return (
    <>
      <Feedback />
      <PatientsTable
        patientsList={patientsList}
        patientsListError={patientsListError}
      />
    </>
  )
}

Patients.layout = 'fullScreen'
Patients.auth = true
export default Patients
```

But I get the following error for `fetcher`:

Argument of type (key: string, id: string, pagination: number) => Promise is not assignable to parameter of type Boolean. The types returned by 'valueOf()' are incompatible between these types. Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

This is the `fetchWithToken` function:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import AlunaLogger from '../libs/AlunaLogger'
import env from '@beam-australia/react-env'

const fetchWithToken = (url: string, token: string, params: object = null) => {
  const logger = AlunaLogger('fetchWithToken')

  // let data = new FormData()

  return axios({
    baseURL: `${env('PUBLIC_ALUNA_API')}/`,
    method: 'GET',
    url,
    params,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
    .then((res) => res.data)
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.response.data)

      logger.error('fetch !res.ok', error.response.data)
      throw error.response
    })
}

export default fetchWithToken
```

Comment: You're missing a return statement before the `fetchWithToken` call, i.e. `return fetchWithToken(key, accessToken, [id, page: pagination])`. If that doesn't fix it, can you also share the code for `fetchWithToken`?

Comment: @juliomalves, sorry for the late reply, I just added the code for `fetchWithToken`.

Answer (score 0):

If I read correctly, in the example on the website you listed. Their fetcher function had a returned a json while yours returns a pending void promise

Would

```
  const fetcher = async (key: string, id: string, pagination: number)=> {
    return fetchWithToken(key, accessToken, [id, page: pagination])
  }
```

or

```
  const fetcher = async (key: string, id: string, pagination: number)=> {
    return await fetchWithToken(key, accessToken, [id, page: pagination])
  }
```

fix your code?

Comment: weird, missed that, your solution should work, but its not. I still get the same error on `fetcher`.